# Recursively copy file-types from directory tree

Tags: ruby, windows, perl, batch-file, copy

I'm trying to find a way to copy all *.exe files (and more, *.dtd, *.obj, etc.) from a directory structure to another path.

For example I might have:

```
Code
   \classdirA
             \bin
                 \classA.exe
   \classdirB
             \bin
                 \classB.exe
   \classdirC
             \bin
                 \classC.exe
   \classdirD
             \bin
                 \classD.exe
```

And I want to copy all *.exe files into a single directory, say `c:\bins`
What would be the best way to do this?

Constraints for my system are:

- Windows
- Can be Perl, Ruby, or .cmd

Anyone know what I should be looking at here?

Comment: When you ask for code, we expect you to show us what you've tried. Otherwise it looks like you're fishing for someone else to do the work for you, without you having put any effort into it.

Comment: I'd use Ruby's [Find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/find/rdoc/index.html) class, which can recursively descend into a directory to find files/directories that meet your criteria. At that point you can copy the file easily using [`FileUtils.cp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp). The documentation for both have examples showing how to use them.

Comment: @the, I believe [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) is the direct link for the `Find` module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do in Ruby, using method [`Dir::glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob) :

```
# this will give you all the ".exe" files recursively from the directory "Code".
Dir.glob("c:/Code/**/*.exe")
```

`**` - Match all directories recursively. This is used to descend into the directory tree and find all files in sub-directories of the current directory, rather than just files in the current directory. This wildcard is explored in the example code.

`*` - Match zero or more characters. A glob consisting of only the asterisk and no other characters or wildcards will match all files in the current directory. The asterisk is usually combined with a file extension, if not more characters to narrow down the search.

Nice blog [*Using Glob with Directories*](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/dir2.htm).

Now to **copy the files** to your required directory, you need to look into the method, [`FileUtils.cp_r`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r) :

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.cp_r Dir.glob("c:/Code/**/*.exe"), "c:\\bins"
```

I just have tested, that [`FileUtils.cp`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp) method will also work, in this case :

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.cp Dir.glob("c:/Code/**/*.exe"), "c:\\bins"
```

My preference here is to use `::cp` method. Because `Dir::glob` is actually collecting all the files having `.exe` extensions recursively, and return them as an array. Now `cp` method is enough here, now just taking each file from the array and coping it to the **target** file.

Why I am not liking in such a situation, the method `::cp_r` ?

Okay, let me explain it here also. As the method name suggests, it will copy ***all*** the files recursively from the **source** to **target** directory. If there is a need to copy specific files recursively, then `::cp_r` wouldn't be able to do this by its own power ( as it can't do selections by itself, which `::glob` can do ). Thus in such a situation, you have to give it the specific file lists, it would then copy then to the **target** directory. If this is the only task, I have to do, then I think we should go with `::cp`, rather than `::cp_r`.

Hope my explanation helps.

Comment: One thing I like about your solution is that it can be used with any operating system, as the Windows-specific part is confided to the two strings.

Answer (score 2):

From `cmd` command line

```
for /r "c:\code" %f in (*.exe) do copy "%~ff" "c:\bins"
```

For usage inside a batch file, double the percent signs (`%%` instead of `%`)

Comment: ok... Sorry.. As multiple language tag it is... Better to mention above, in which platform you are using. BTW, can you give a documentation link of the above ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, no, plain cmd command. It says: `for` each `*.exe` file located below (`/r` = recursive) the `c:\code` folder, execute a copy command, taking as source the full name of the file (`%f` = reference to the file, `%~ff` = file with full path). You can execute `for /?` from command line for a reference and sample usage of the command.

Answer (score 1):

Windows shell (`cmd`) command:

```
for /r code %q in (*.exe) do copy "%q" c:\bin
```

Double the `%` characters if you place this in a batch file.